# Where's the technical details to look at

Tags: discussion, declined-flags

I flagged [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/31572739/1380752) which was declined for

> declined - flags should not be used to indicate technical inaccuracies, or an altogether wrong answer

I...didn't think I was flagging for a wrong answer.

It's a bunch of links with one reference to "you can get the jar here".

I looked to see if the answer was in this castle or not. I searched every room but still found just links as it seems useless with the hyperlinks stripped away.

I flagged as NaA but maybe I should have left some comment with the flag? I don't know what it would say because the "answer" doesn't *really* give any technical answer at all. Just says, "Look over there, then check that place for more information, and you can also find information in that hut over yonder".

It seems like a really nice comment to me but that's it. Heck, two of the links are even identical.

Was this a simple oversight (it happens...I missed something once a long time ago)? Or was this a codeMagicFailure and I should have done something differently?

Comment: NAA wasn't the correct flag choice for an answer that is an attempt (albeit poor) to answer the question. and, it does appear to have solved the problem in this case (it's accepted.) I would have just downvoted and moved on, or downvoted and added a better answer.

Comment: @KevinB an attempt to answer a question with only links is, from my understanding, NAA. The fact that it was accepted should have no bearing on the validity of a flag.

Comment: It's a low quality answer. NAA is for cases where the answer should have instead been a comment, or another question entirely.

Comment: @KevinB that's not what I have gotten from [Your answer is in another castle](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/225370/your-answer-is-in-another-castle-when-is-an-answer-not-an-answer) and this is how I've always flagged them and usually accepted. That's why I'm trying to figure out if there is something different in this situation.

Comment: @Kevin: Strip the link-markup, and try to gather *any* pertinent info from the leftovers. There isn't anything.

Comment: @Deduplicator - Include the jar. It says it right in plain text. The links give even more context. It was a bad answer, but you would have to be blind to miss the suggestion.

Comment: @codeMagic: your understanding is incorrect. *If* the attempt to answer *without the link* no longer is readable, it is a NAA. This was an attempt to answer.

Comment: Related: [When to flag an answer as “it is not an answer”?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/265552/1393766)

Answer (score 9):

Whenever I see a NAA flag on a post that is clearly an attempt at answering that (as the case is here), I decline such an answer with the *don't flag incorrect answers*, because I'm assuming you thought the answer was incorrect.

In other words, I don't see why you thought this wasn't an answer. It clearly is an attempt at answering the question *how can I add this library without a dependency*. The OP thought it was useful enough to mark as accepted. I assumed you flagged it because you thought the answer was wrong.

I'll use the more generic *moderator reviewed your flag but didn't see evidence* rejection reason in future.

In general, I feel that people are too quick to flag answers with a link in them; in a huge number of these cases it is the *question* that is at fault.

Comment: So something like, "This tutorial is your answer" with a link to a tutorial is an answer? Because I don't see any difference in the two. My point is that I don't see what the attempt, without the links, is at answering the question. I honestly don't think I'm one to flag quickly since I take time, think of *why* I think it isn't an answer (or whatever the flagging reason), and they are generally accepted. In fact, in the Android chat room, I often tell people not to flag a lot of posts when they ask my opinion because I know they are wrong/will be declined.

Comment: The only thing I can see that *might* make it an answer without the links is, here is the jar file. Which, I suppose, *could* be an attempt at answering.

Comment: @codeMagic: depends on the question. *Gimme a tutorial* -> then close the question, there is little point in flagging the answer. *Tell me how to frob the foobnar* -> flag the answer, that's not going to go anywhere.

Comment: @codeMagic: sure, technically, "this tutorial is your answer" is not an answer by our standards, but if the question was directly asking for such answers, why punish the answerer directly? Get rid of the question instead.

Comment: @codeMagic: and yes, the *here is the jar file* thing makes it an attempt at answering. When in doubt, we try to err on the side of not deleting.

Comment: Ok, I'm still not completely in agreement but I understand on being cautious. And I will keep this in mind for the future.

Answer (score 2):

From [Your answer is in another castle: when is an answer not an answer?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/225370/178816)

[image]

Emphasis mine.

The answer you cite is not a particularly nice answer, but at least it meets the qualifications of a small explanation or piece of guidance. That it contains a link is irrelevant, because the small amount of explanation is enough to qualify it as an answer. Does that mean the answer is useful? In my opinion not really, so feel free to downvote in this type of situation. On the other hand, the OP did accept the answer as a solution so perhaps there was some value found in the answer to them.

Overall, the shown question and answer are rather poor in quality and most likely will not survive the test of time.

Comment: I understand that but my question is, if the flag is invalid, then what part of the "answer" contributes to "it meets the qualifications of a small explanation or piece of guidance."? Also, I'm not complaining about my flag getting declined which is why I was hesitant to post. But I want to understand the question stated above to make sure I am getting the whole process.

Comment: @codeMagic - It is low quality, and the question is basically how do I add a dependency. The answer points to the issue with adding that dependency and includes a link to the actual jar file for the code, presumably. Overall it is not a good question and answer, however, that part still "answers" the question with its attempt. The only time you should really be flagging as not an answer for links is when there is *only* a link. Otherwise just downvote and let the community handle it over time as opposed to requiring a moderator to step in.

Comment: Also, let's be clear. This meta post is a complaint about a declined flag. You even tagged it as a discussion about declined-flags.

Comment: I understand and agree with everything you are saying. *Except* that this answer *is just links*. Take away the hyperlinks and which part of it answers the question?

Comment: I tagged it as declined flags because it's about uh...the use of declined flags. Otherwise, I would have also used specific-answer. But it's not *just* this answer. I was looking for an explanation if there is an answer in there, that's all.

Comment: @codeMagic - It would still break down to including the jar will solve the dependency problem. Which is the overall message of the answer. Could there be more there? Of course, which is why it is getting downvotes. But does it at least live up to the very bare minimum to prevent a mod from deleting it from a single flag? Yes.

Comment: I can see your point about the jar and looked at that several times before and after flagging but that is still a borderline answer. Just mentioning something that is language/framework related doesn't make it an answer. But I guess that might have been enough in this case.

Comment: Borderline definitely. It is a flat out bad answer. But it isn't egregious enough to warrant moderator intervention and the overall community has enough tools already in place to handle situations like this one.

Comment: tbqh this _does_ seem NAA to me. It has no value on its own at all.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit - Did you look at Shog9's guidance? One of the example posts would be "You probably want a" without the link. I am not sure why you think this would any different than the shown example by him. This type of minutia just wastes moderator time. The answer is an answer. A low quality one. To a poorly posed question. It wont be around for long and there is no real point. Flag NAA if you want, but it will just be declined more than likely and also is akin to saying "here, you deal with this" even though you already have all the tools to handle a low quality answer.

Comment: @TravisJ: You're not listening. A post whose only value is links _isn't_ an answer. It physically is not one. I'm not claiming that bad answers are not answers. I'm saying that this is _not an answer_. You cannot read it and have any clue how to solve the question. And why does it have to go to moderators? Doesn't this flag put the answer in a review queue? Hmm

Comment: Travis, withough the link, that answer is "You probably want a FileOutputStream", which is a really short answer. But that's distinctly different from "You probably want a". He's not saying remove the link, but the link markup, so the text which was made a link stays.

Comment: @Deduplicator - The continuation was implied. As in a fill in the blank. The qualifying part of the answer simply making a suggestion was enough to show that it was attempting to answer the question.

Comment: I'd have to agree that this case isn't equivalent to the posted example. Without link markup, the posted answer contains the following text: "If have only Read it, u would have found this. It gives u the link to the .jar file. Here is the Android Version of the Library and here is the direct link to its .jar format." - which basically says "look harder you idiot" in slightly politer but lazily typed words. There are zero keywords in that answer which are useful for finding the answer if the links break.

Comment: @IMSoP - All of which led to its removal by the community, which is the way it is supposed to work. Flagging it is an incorrect course of action as it does attempt to answer the question posed. Note that the question itself is barely a sentence long.

Comment: @TravisJ It may not meet the criteria *you* would like us to apply to such cases, but it does meet the criteria set out by Shog9 in the linked meta post, i.e. if you remove the link markup, the text alone does not contain any information. You are of course entitled to disagree with Shog9, but if so don't quote their reasoning in support of your own.

Comment: @IMSoP - Removing the links still provides an attempt at answering the question. It suggests to solve the dependency problem by including the jar. It is fairly obvious and I am not sure why this type of nuance needs moderator, or review queue, intervention. It is a low quality answer, but it *is* an answer. I am not disagreeing with Shog9, because he *also* doesn't want moderator time wasted. And he *especially* stated not to complain about a flag wasting moderator time on meta. This entire course of action was an act of futility.

Comment: @TravisJ OK, so it seems the case comes down to whether the word "jar" is considered to add information to an answer regarding Java. I admit that is a grey line, so I guess the  fundamental lesson is "if in doubt, don't flag, just downvote" (and, if we Assume Good Faith, comment to explain how the answer could be improved).

Comment: @IMSoP - I think that is a very accurate observation.